# Read txt with delimeter and multiple spaces

Tags: c++, ifstream

I have a text file where the delimiter is '&'. However, the first column is text and may contain spaces as well - How can I properly read it ? The text looks like

```
selection according to criteria A & 2312
```

some other  selection according to criteria B & 345

Please note that the text in first column can contain more than one word (ie more spaces from one to another line). I ve tried something

```
char ch;
ch="&";
   ifstream filein;
   filein.open("selection.txt");
   while (1) {
      data >> c1 >> char >>c2 ;

        cut1.push_back(c1);
        cut2.push_back(c2);

      if (!data.good()) break;

}
```

but this does not work...

thanks in advance

Comment: the problem is the multiple spacing in the first field...so no need for downvoting that easily...

Comment: _The problem_ goes away, if you use `std::getline()` to read. See the answers in the duplicate. Do better research next time to avoid downvotes.

Answer (score 1):

Read the whole line using `std::getline`. Then split the line into two substrings using the string [`find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) and [`substr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) functions.

If you have multiple fields, then do the splitting in a loop until you can't find the separator anymore.

Comment: tokenizing might be a better option than repeated find.

Comment: Could be done with two `getline()` statements as well, 1st one using `'&'` as delimiter.

Comment: would it be possible to give a small working example ?

Comment: @Just_Newbie Stop help vampiring. Just research upon [`std::getline()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) and check what might be the best use for solving your problem.